# Redirecting from one function to another is different for ClassName/index and ClassName [CodeIgniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Isn't redirecting a function with `ClassName/index` and only `ClassName` same?

I am using a Login function to check if user is logged in or not, and upon verifying I am redirecting it to the Dashboard and I am only using `redirect('/ClassName')`.

Surprisingly, the index function of that Class is not getting called and garbage session value is being used, unless I manually append `/index` at the end of that Class and in this case, the current session value is being used.

Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion you should call your login function in the constructor of controller. Usually ' redirect('/ClassName') ' this should call the index function.

Comment: Yes I am doing that, if the session's not set, it will redirect to Login Controller...

Comment: as a general rule, you should always use controller/method pairs when redirecting (even if you're redirecting to an `index` method). Yes, even if CI loads the `index` method automatically if the corresponding URI segment is empty. That said, the leading slash in your redirect is not supposed to be there, you should just `redirect('classname');` or `redirect('classname/index');` as the leading slash is interpreted as a segment delimiter

Comment: @JavierLarroulet, yes removing the leading slash solved the issue... Thanks..

Comment: @theNewbie Great. I'll post it as an answer so you can upvote it and mark as solved so it can help others that face the same issue

Comment: @JavierLarroulet, thank you... and yes please do

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should always user controller/method pairs when redirecting, even if you are redirecting to an `index` method, basically for standardization and future-proofing. Yes, CI loads the index method by default when the corresponding URI segment is empty, but it's good practice to make it a habit of passing the whole controller/method pair.

Having said that, the leading slash in your redirect is not supposed to be there, you should just `redirect('classname');` or `redirect('classname/index');` as the leading slash is interpreted as a segment delimiter, which may cause a whole lot of issues like the ones you've experienced.